# How to persist changes to DBModel files from being updated from update model from database wizard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using entity framework in MVC5, I am using database first approach. After creating some tables, I go to .cs file, and do some changes like adding data annotations, so that users get correct error messages. Everything is ok until I run next time the update model from database wizard, after which .cs file gets refreshed, and I lost changes done to this file. Is there a way to persist changes to these files after running this wizard. or the only way is to write separate viewmodel classes just to add data annotations.

Comment: You might need to follow `Code First` approach, rather than `Database First` approach. If you still want to follow database first approach, then make sure all the constraints are in place on database columns.

Comment: The constraints are there but its not for client side, like a field is marked not null, but at the time of form submission its not validating on client side.